# AWS Glue Crawler is not creating tables in schema

Tags: amazon-athena, aws-glue

I am trying AWS Glue crawler to create tables in athena.
The source that I am pulling it from is a Postgresql server. The crawler is able to parse the tables, create metadata and show the tables and columns in the Glue data catalog but the tables are not added in athena despite the fact that I have added the target database from athena.
Not sure why this is happening
Also, if I choose a csv source from s3 then it is able to create a table in athena with _csv as a suffix
Any help?

Comment: you seem to have your files inside a database and not s3. Athena will not be able to help you with querying databases.

Answer (score 7):

Athena doesn't recognize my Postgres tables added by Glue either. My guess is that Athena is used for querying data stored on S3, so it's not working for database queries.

Also, to be able to query your CSV files on S3, files need to be under a folder crawled by glue. If you just crawl a single file with Glue, Athena will return 0 records from the query.